# If $\sin(\pi/3+t)+\sin (\pi/3-t)=p$, then evaluate $\sin(\pi/3+t)\cdot \sin(\pi/3-t)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Knowing that 
>   $$\sin\left(\frac\pi3+t\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi3-t\right)=p$$ 
>   evaluate 
>   $$\sin\left(\frac\pi3+t\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac\pi3-t\right)$$

I found that $\cos t = \dfrac{p}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Welcome! Please tell us what you know and what have you tried. Also, use LaTex to be more readable friendly :)

Comment: I found that the cost=p/sqrt 3

Comment: Gives us your full computation. Also, why is useful to compute the $\cos(t)$? Explaining helps you to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\sin(\pi/3+t)+\sin(\pi/3-t)=\sqrt{3}\cos(t)=p$$ and $$\sin(\pi/3+t)\sin(\pi/3-t)=1/4(1+2\cos(2t))$$. Now use that $$\cos(2t)=2\cos^2(t)-1$$